# C# Run another program without copying .exe file

Tags: c#

I have a program that runs another extern program by using the Process.Start()-Method with the full path (like "C:\some\folders\here\externprogram.exe").

The problem I have is that whenever I click the button that runs it, my program will copy that into the folder, that my program is in - and runs it there (like "D:\MyProgram\externprogram.exe"). Unfortuanally this extern program relies on other stuff being next to it and I don't want to copy that other stuff into my program folder too.

Is there any way to run a program whereever it is instead of copying it?

Comment: Well, then don't copy the file then? Execute it at the location it currently is at? Why is that not an option?

Comment: Not a good idea - this might mess up the program folder - and it works by setting `WorkingDirectory` as @Berkay and @ChristophKN explained below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `WorkingDirectory`;

```
using (Process pp = new Process())
       {
           pp.StartInfo.FileName = "externalAppUrl";
           pp.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "directoryNameToRun";
           pp.Start();
       }
```

For More information check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx),

Hope helps.

Comment: `Process` implements `IDisposable` that's why it's reasonable to wrap it into `using`:  `using(Process pp = new Process()) {
pp.StartInfo.FileName = ... }`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to run a program whereever it is instead of copying it?

**Yes**

The [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a constructor parameter called [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).
The [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) has a Property called [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx). This property sets a value, that the [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) should start in this directory. 
It won't copy any files to your directory.

**Usage**

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(PathToYourExe) 
{
  WorkingDirectory = "The directory from the exe." 
}
```

Starting your process is now easy.

```
using(Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
  // Your code while process will run.
}
```